# Create package version with namespace: Error to access custom field in FlexiPage

Tags: custom-object, package, namespace, flexipages

Hi I understand it don't need to add `NAMESPACE` in prefix when access `<FIELD>`, but I still have case like below.

My package have relationship between 3 objects: Contact - Affiliations - Account.

Normally, Contact can access to Account.`<FIELD>` if this is connected to Affiliations.

Everything was fines, if I access `<FIELD>` is standard. But when I tried to connect `<FIELD__c>` custom field. it throws error

```
Location_Record_Page: Component [lst:dynamicRelatedList] attribute [relatedListFieldAliases]: Could not find column [Contact.Grade__c] in related list [Affiliations__r] for entity [Account]
```

```
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>relatedListApiName</name>
                    <value>Affiliations__r</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>relatedListDisplayType</name>
                    <value>ADVGRID</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>relatedListFieldAliases</name>
                    <valueList>
                        <valueListItems>
                            <value>NAME</value>
                        </valueListItems>
                        <valueListItems>
                            <value>Contact.Grade__c</value>
                        </valueListItems>
                    </valueList>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
```

How we resolve this problem?

Comment: You are using Affiliations__r, this object has relationship with contact? if you respond to yes, can you try using CONTACT.Grade__c
when you work Flexipage, Salesforce work with sensitive system, is strange but is true.